# How to have a same static IP address in all the networks

Tags: iptables, ip, routing, gateway

Imagine, I have an application at office which is bound to use 10.x.x.x IP address once it is installed. The gateway of this address will be 10.x.x.1 and this IP is set as static.

So, when I move the machine to another network, let's assume, my home, the IP and the gateway will still remain the same inside the machine as it is set as static, but the actual gateway of the network now will be something like 192.168.x.1 and the network connection actually fails.

My question is how to use the same IP in my home network as well and have connection by using the new gateway that is 192.x.x.1. May be using some kind of IP table rules??

**EDIT:** If this is not possible, can I keep a router between the machine and the original router, and when I move my machine , I move with this router. The IP address of the intermediate router may change, but the machine still gets the same static IP with connection. Is this possible? If so, how?

**Solved!!** The jump router helped!! There is default way in routers for configuring it to get DHCP assignment from the ISP/original router and distribute static IP for its connections. The IP and gateway for the machines from this jump router stays same even when it is moved. Only drawback is that the jump router has to move with the machine.

Comment: You would have to reconfigure you home network to use the same 10.x.x.x network (this is non-routable space - just like 192.168.x.x). Make your home router 10.x.x.1 and set your dhcp server to not use the reserved static IP.

Comment: You cannot use the same IP address in a network that has a different address space. You have to use the same address space (ie. 10.x.x.x) in your home network as in your office network.

Comment: Applications should not be "bound" to use fixed IP addresses. Please, fix this problem in your application.